# Angular Service Parameter undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I have a service that is called in a component and it was working before I tried to implement some code reuse tactics, but now the http client isn't coming in as defined. The component calls the appropriate function like this:

```
//actions object that maps the request on the object
//split between the different areas of the app.
serviceActions: {[name: string]: {[name: string]:(...args: any[]) => Observable<any>}} = {
    'Customer':{
        GetCategories: this._service.GetCategories,
    }
    'Admin':{...}
};
// source string referenced in the function call
source: string = 'Customer';

//the actual call being made
this.serviceActions[this.Source].GetCategories(...).subscribe(...)
```

This code is calling a function on a service that takes `http` as a parameter:

```
//service constructor:
 constructor(private httpClient: Http) { }
//service method:
public GetCategories(showAll = false, parentId = 0): Observable<Array<SelectModel>> {
        let link = AppSettings.API_COMMON_CATEGORIES;
        let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('showAll', showAll.toString());
        params.set('parentId', parentId != null ? parentId.toString() : null);
        let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.search = params;

        return this.httpClient.get(link, requestOptions).map(response => {
            let result = JSON.parse(response.json());
            let list = new Array<SelectModel>();
            let caregories: Array<any> = result;

            caregories.forEach(category => {
                list.push(this.CreateSelectModel(category));
            });

            return list;
        });
    }
```

This was working fine when the service method was called directly, but now that I've implemented the `serviceActions` object, it's saying `cannot read property get of undefined`

what gives?

Comment: This is an unrelated note, but you should be using the `HttpClient` class, rather than `Http`; `Http` has been deprecated for a while. For example, you don't need to json.parse in your map with `HttpClient`

Comment: It's also a good idea to follow the TypeScript/JavaScript conventions when naming methods: it's strongly advised to name methods in camelCase instead of PascalCase as with what you would do in dotnet or C languages.

Comment: First a few things, 1. The app is written in Angular 4.3, and cannot be upgraded currently, was originally written with `Http` and I need to think the process through before migrating. 2. We're primarily a C# shop, so Pascal Case is preferred with us.

Comment: Also can confirm that it's putting it in a dictionary like this that's causing the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue stems from the fact that packing functions on the object dereferences `this` from the class where it was defined. To get around this, we should wrap the function package in another anonymous function passing along the parameters.

So instead of:

```
serviceActions: {[name: string]: {[name: string]:(...args: any[]) => Observable<any>}} = {
    'Customer':{
        GetCategories: this._service.GetCategories,
    }
    'Admin':{...}
};
```

it should really be:

```
serviceActions: {[name: string]: {[name: string]:(...args: any[]) => Observable<any>}} = {
    'Customer':{
        GetCategories: (params) => this._service.GetCategories(params),
    }
    'Admin':{...}
};
```

to preserve the reference to `this` in the class.